# How do I make JavaScript behavior run on every page load?

Tags: 8, javascript

I don't know how to run my Drupal.behaviours.mybehaviour on every page load.

Here's my code example that run only once, when I load the page is no longer run my code, how can I change that from once to run on every page load:

```
       Drupal.behaviors.searchFilter = {
            attach: function (context) {
               once('searchFilter', 'html', context).forEach( function () {
                   console.log("function run");
               });
            }
       }
```

Comment: Drupal.behaviors is already run on every page load, so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: For example:  How can I run console.log("test loading page")  display on every page load.

Comment: `Drupal.behaviors.searchFilter = {
            attach: function (context) {console.log("test loading page");}};`

Comment: @Jaypan thanks for that, how can I attach my library so it get called on every page load.  Right now I attached inside my custom module on a checkbox element, but it only execute when the form is submit.

Comment: `Drupal.beviours` is already called on every page load. So I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: thanks @Jaypan - I'm investigate further, could be a cache issue.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, you have to attach your library using the `hook_page_attachments` This hook will attach your library on every page, so it will run on page load.

Then you can execute your js script like the following:

```
 Drupal.behaviors.searchFilter = {
            attach: function (context) {
                console.log("function run");
            }
       }
```